# Sort two Lists<T> together as one?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two List which I am accessing by index (e.g. `Name[10]`, `Date[10]`). They're closely tied, so `Name[10]` is related to `Date[10]` and vice versa.

This design has worked well but now I need to sort them. I can sort them both individually but obviously that would remove the relationship between the two lists and make them worthless.

I thought about using a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` instead but it seems I can only access that by Key (which is also unworkable). Essentially I need three things, two values and one index which I can iterate through numerically (not `foreach`).

Can anyone help? It seems I either need to change data-structure or work out how to sort two distinct `List<T>` together...

```
public class Results
{ 
public List<string> Name { get; set; }
public List<DateTime> Date{ get; set; }
}

for (int x = 0; x < results; x++)
{ z.N = results.Name[X]; z.D = results.Date[x]; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're fighting against doing the obvious solution which involves a *little* bit of upfront work: creating a type to encapsulate the name/date pair.

That's *absolutely* what you should do. Then you can have one list, sort it by name or by date or whatever you want, and you never need to worry about the two lists getting out of sync etc.

If your `Results` class doesn't do anything apart from contain those two lists, you can actually end up with the same number of types - you can ditch `Results` entirely, in favour of `List<Result>` where `Result` has a name and a date.

Comment: he can using generic dictionary

Comment: @AMH: The OP already considered that - it doesn't preserve order, and it's fundamentally *not* what he's trying to store. He wants a list, but of two different values.

Comment: As an added benefit, this solution will allow you to give an explicit name to whatever concept you're trying to represent, and additionally you can embed logic for manipulating this data within the very same type, rather than having it possibly strewn all around your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 16):

Use the [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3.aspx) overload that takes an array of keys and an array of values, it does precisely what you want. (This method has been available since .NET 2.0.)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question as it was stated. Pairing Name and Date together like the other answers suggest is generally good advice, but there are situations where storing two symmetric arrays makes sense. Specifically, using a 'Structure of Arrays' data layout in a computationally intensive algorithm.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I did not know this feature existed.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Tuple<string,DateTime> NameDateList {get; set; }
```

Is an easy way to accomplish what you want, but for clarity you are probably better off making a custom type to house them such as:

```
public class NameDate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
List<NameDate> NameDateList {get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and keep the two things together:

```
public class NameAndDate {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then you keep them in one list (`List<NameAndDate>`):

If you want to sort by the name, add a `IComparer` implementation to `NameAndDate`, then you can just call `Sort()` on the list.

If you want to keep access to the Name and the Date, add accessor methods to Results, like

```
public string GetName(int index) {
  return list[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called "Result" with two properties

```
public class Result
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public DateTime Date { set;get;}
}
```

Now you may create a List of this class

```
List<Result> objListResult=new List<Result>();
```

Now in your case, If you want, you may read the content of your indidual List and put it to our new List. (This is only purticular to your case, if you really want to move data from your old Lists to our new List. If possible you may update the code where you load data to two List(that is the correct way) so that it will load data to our new List of Type Result and avoid this porting code to move data to new List.

```
 for(int i=0;i<Name.Count;i++)
 {
   objListResult.Add(new Result { Name =Name[i].ToString(), Date[i].ToString() });
 }
```

You can access the Items from the new List like this

```
 objListResult[2].Date
```

will give you the Date Stored for the second object in the list

```
 objListResult[2].Name
```

will give you the Name Stored for the second object in the list

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom type to hold a value, or if you only need to use it in the scope of a single method you could use an anonymous type as follows.

```
var namesAndDates = MyNames
    .Select((name, i) => new {name, date = MyDates[i]});
```

From here the two values are no longer loosely tied. Now you can sort them.

```
var sortedNamesAndDates = namesAndDates.OrderBy(a => a.date);
```

Or whatever else you'll need to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary with Key Name , and value Date

and U can after that sort them easily